# Create Dictionary ( topic as key and embeddings as value) from data frame contents

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

a dataframe containing following contents

```
            0                1           2          3            4          5        
0    reviewers#0        -0.016271    0.011541    0.011903    -0.001355   0.008702
1    reviewers#1         -0.037961   0.033415    0.020643    0.004748    0.014523
2    reviewers#2         -0.019863   0.019906    0.017248    0.006216    0.008826
3    reviewers#3         -0.021029   0.016401    0.010772    0.001874    0.005772
4    reviewers#4         -0.013409   0.011703    0.011249    0.000111    0.009319
5    reviewers#5         -0.008549   0.007816    0.007859    0.000984    0.005491
6    reviewers#6         -0.01634    0.017007    0.014637    0.005241    0.008135
7    reviewers#7         -0.017075   0.016119    0.013666    0.00314     0.008786
8    reviewers#8         -0.030823   0.020217    0.012402    -0.003165   0.009643
9    reviewers#9         -0.038311   0.026252    0.017619    0.003568    0.003972
10   confiscated#0       -0.007147   0.007387    0.010867    0.000735    0.011244
11   confiscated#1       -0.016917   0.014412    0.016182    0.001859    0.015596
12   confiscated#2       -0.004854   0.004091    0.005075    -0.000566   0.00458
13   confiscated#3       -0.02642    0.021311    0.018871    -0.001843   0.017033
14   confiscated#4      -0.016161    0.013325    0.013113    -0.001036   0.011385
15   confiscated#5       -0.0131     0.0117      0.013829    -0.000861   0.01225
16   confiscated#6       -0.006454   0.005335    0.006634    -0.001038   0.006322
17   confiscated#7      -0.006855    0.005225    0.007626    -0.003071   0.009048
18   confiscated#8      -0.019227    0.015683    0.016805    -0.004709   0.019453
19   confiscated#9      -0.010685    0.011237    0.011653    0.003006    0.007464
```

Now we want a dictionary as below

```
dictionary = {
            0:{[ reviewers#0 -0.016271    0.011541    0.011903    -0.001355   0.008702], [confiscated#0 -0.007147  0.007387 0.010867 0.000735 0.011244]}
            1:{[ reviewers#1 -0.016271 0.011541 0.011903 -0.001355   0.008702], [confiscated#1 -0.007147  0.007387 0.010867 0.000735 0.011244]},
            .
            .
            .
            9: {[ reviewers#9 -0.016271 0.011541 0.011903 -0.001355 0.008702], [confiscated#9 -0.007147 0.007387 0.010867 0.000735 0.011244]}
 }
```

Hints: In the dataframe content each row represents topical embedding of each words (we have 10 topics #0 to #9) e.g. reviewers#0 to reviewers#9 we can get topic (0 to 9) for each row in the dataframe by applying flowing idea:

```
for inx in dataframe.index:
 topic = inx % 10
```

Thank you very much for your Idea and help

Comment: See [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future questions.

Comment: Is `dictionary` the desired result, or the current result?

Comment: Why does `dictionary` have duplicate curly braces? It it supposed to be a *set* of dictionaries, and if so, why?

Comment: Yes dictionary is the desired output. Actually I am asking how can I get similar to dictionary from dataframe contents shown above .. Thank you for your time

Comment: We don't need duplicate curly braces want some thing like,  dictionary = {
           0: [value1,value2],
           1: [value1,value2],
           9: [value1, value2]
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you're after:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {0: 'reviewers#0', 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0},
    {0: 'reviewers#1', 1: 4.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 6.0},
    {0: 'confiscated#0', 1: 7.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 9.0},
    {0: 'confiscated#1', 1: 10.0, 2: 11.0, 3: 12.0},
])

print(df)

result = defaultdict(list)
for _, values in df.iterrows():
    values = list(values)
    result[int(values[0].split('#')[1])] += [values[1:]]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
               0     1     2     3
0    reviewers#0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1    reviewers#1   4.0   5.0   6.0
2  confiscated#0   7.0   8.0   9.0
3  confiscated#1  10.0  11.0  12.0
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]], 1: [[4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]]})
```

I.e. the dataframe has the structure you described, the `result` dictionary is the result you require?

If you need the `defaultdict` to be a plain dict, there's few more minor changes, or you can cast it - but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I think I made you a little confused, Actually I want  all words in topic_0 under the key 0: some thing like dictionary ={
  0: {['confiscated#0', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ['reviewers#0', 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]}
  1: {['confiscated#1', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ['reviewers#1', 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]}
  2: {['confiscated#2', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ['reviewers#2', 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]}
 }

Comment: I see what you mean, updated the answer.